# ERROR: 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'created_at'

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Trying to create a table, when executing the query it gives this error:
`ERROR: 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'created_at'`
The whole command is this:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    created_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Comment: Works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=353efc4e0dbaed97dc2a18fa9c0a95d6

Comment: This fails with the error you see in mysql 5.5 and succeeds in 5.6- what version are you on - see fiddle from @nick

Comment: 'As of MySQL 5.6.5, TIMESTAMP and DATETIME columns can be automatically initializated and updated to the current date and time (that is, the current timestamp). Before 5.6.5, this is true only for TIMESTAMP,' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Comment: MySQL 5.6.5 will have it's ninth birthday in two days - if you are really using any older version, it's time for an update!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using some MySQL version less than 5.6.5. For MySQL version 5.5, if you want to set default value, you would have to use "TIMESTAMP" type, instead of "DATETIME" type. Hope TIMESTAMP type is not a problem for you.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked.